# How to create a "DisplayFormulaNumbered" cell inside a "Text" cell

Tags: cells, counter

Is it possible to put a "DisplayFormulaNumbered" cell (containing just an equation) inside a larger outside cell (a "Text" cell with a thin frame)? See pic below for my desired look.

Notice we would have left alignment and no counter for the outside cell (the "Text" cell that containing everything) while the inside cell (the "DisplayFormulaNumbered" cell containing just the equation) will have centered alignment and a counter that stays current with other "DisplayFormulaNumbered" cells.

Also notice the counter is displayed on the SAME LINE as the equation and INSIDE the frame.  See below.

[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to create this structure of a cell of one style within a cell of different style.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'd like to know too.  A hack would be to set the lower cell margin on the upper cell to zero, and the upper cell margin to zero on the lower cell.  You could create a style sheet with new styles (e.g., NumberEquationPrelude and NumberedEquationEquation) with those margins.

Comment: If you want the box, just frame three sides of each half.

Comment: I guess that you want that the enumeration of the equation should be automatically updated in a usual way, do you? I would also like to see such a solution.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Yes exactly.  I was able to create something that formats and increments correctly for one or more numbered equations by creating extra counters in the stylesheet that update in parallel to the “display formula numbered” counter.  I used these for the numbered equations inside.  Everything stays in sync and formatted nicely as I add equations but can’t figure out how to keep them updated when the deleting equations.  I’ll work on a better solution.